# How to execute DQL query in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

I am trying to get objects from DQL query. 
Here is my code :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Item::class);

$items = $em->createQuery($getQuery);
$items = $query->getResult();

$getQuery = DQL query string : SELECT from Entity WHERE ...
```

I am receiving error : Undefined method 'createQuery'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!
I don't understand it, bcz this example is copied from official documentation.
How I can execute DQL query in queryBuilder/createQuery?

Comment: Does `Item::class` entity class have a repository?

Comment: Yes.
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * ItemRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class ItemRepository extends EntityRepository
{
}

Comment: What is in `getDoctrine()`?

Comment: What do you mean @OluwafemiSule ? Nothing inside ( ).

Comment: I mean the method body for `getDoctrine()`. Did you write it?

Comment: Yes, I wrote. But now I realised that my IDE suggests that method createQuery not exists. Only createQueryBuilder. @OluwafemiSule

Comment: Using createQueryBuilder means you'll need to build the query using methods of the query builder instance.

Answer (score 1):

Entity manager has a `createQuery` method.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$query = $em->createQuery($getQuery);

$items = $query->getResult();
```

Repository has a `createQueryBuilder` method.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$qb = $em->getRepository(Item::class)->createQueryBuilder();
$query = qb->select('[columns]')->from('Entity')->where('[condition]')->getQuery();
$items = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Some progress. What method is used to get results?
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getResult" of class "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager".
500 Internal Server Error - UndefinedMethodException

Comment: My IDE doesn't see method createQuery. Something is wrong with USE maybe?

Comment: Referenced method is not found in subject class.

Comment: `createQuery` is called on an entity manager while `execute` on a query object

Comment: If you're using a repository, you can build a query with a query builder using `createQueryBuilder` and subsequent query builder methods

Comment: Ok, I can do this with QueryBuilder but how I can use DQL there? ->where() ?